Another NetExtender instance is already running. NetExtender will now exit in linux

I Have provisioned the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine on the GCP Console.
We've installed xRDP to facilitate remote desktop access.
So we installed the NetExtender on Linux through RDP
Install NetExtender
After installation when i Open NetExtender GUI in applications. It's showing Another NetExtender instance is already running. NetExtender will now exit

So can anyone help on this issue
Thanks

have you tried to reboot?
